# How do I access the locals() dict of a different scope?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am writing a debugger and I need to access the local variables of a previously called frame

For eg, I have a code like this:

```
def foo():
    ...
    result = bar(args) # bar is some function 
    locals_of_bar = ...#get the locals() dict of the frame in which `bar` was called
```

EDIT: I have updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Functions don't have locals. Stack frames (concrete function calls) have.

Comment: Your question seems technically incorrect, since it works on stack calls and locals are created and destroyed on calling and returning from a method.

Answer (score -1):

The best you can do is :

```
def foo():
   print bar_locals()

def bar_locals():
   a=1
   b=2
   return locals()
```

**Alternatively :**

You can do something like:

locals_of_methods = {}

def bar():
    # perform the functionality
    global locals_of_methods
    locals_of_methods['bar':locals()]
    # return

After executing `bar()`, you will have the locals in `locals_of_methods`

Comment: I want to do it dynamically, so I don't want to edit the function to insert a `return locals()` for every function I debug. I was wondering whether it is possible to get the data from a previously executed frame.

Comment: Please understand that `func` is loaded to a stack and executed with its `locals` and then its unloaded, so basically it unloads everything that was just for the `func` and therefore gets rid of the locals. Having said that you have to export them somewhere to access them later or on the fly.

Comment: You are right, but it is possible to extract the `locals` of a frame from a traceback. Werkzeug does this - https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/bfb2d6f3ed4c00fde3b115225fc26f6f1ded365c/werkzeug/debug/tbtools.py#L174 . I guess I will have to make do with just tracebacks for now.